# can anybody suggest the Alternate of "intersect" & "Minus" for MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

GOT error for the following query in MYSQL(version5.1)

```
SELECT year,month,sum(fact_1),sum(fact_2),sum(fact_3),sum(fact_4)
from(
select year,month,fact_1,fact_2,0 as fact_3,0 as fact_4 from table_1
intersect
select year,month,0 as fact_1,0 as fact_2,fact_3,fact_4 from table_2
) as combined_table
group by month,year
```

Error Line with code#1064:-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'select
>   year,month,0 as fact_1,0 as
>   fact_2,fact_3,fact_4 from table_2 ) as
>   ct g' at line 5

but following query was giving desired Result:-

```
SELECT year,month,sum(fact_1),sum(fact_2),sum(fact_3),sum(fact_4)
from(
select year,month,fact_1 ,fact_2,0 as fact_3,0 as fact_4 from table_1
union
select year,month,0 as fact_1,0 as fact_2,fact_3,fact_4 from table_2
) as ct
group by month,year
```

Can anybody tell what error i am committing?
can Anybody help me to understand the root cause behind the Problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can fake `INTERSECT` quite easily using an `INNER` (self) `JOIN`, this way you’ll only get rows from both resultsets:

```
    SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`
      FROM `a`
INNER JOIN `b`
     USING (`id`, `name`)
```

`MINUS` can be faked with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`
      FROM `a`
 LEFT JOIN `b`
     USING (`id`, `name`)
     WHERE `b`.`id` IS NULL
```

Comment: @ knittl, thanx for the reply,is there any alternate soltution

Comment: why do you ned an alternate solution when you have a working one? alternate solutions would be using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: there are some specific requirement of my project,i can perform operations on the 2 INNER SELECT queries only ...I know this is strange these are some limitation of my API

Comment: have you ever considered using _views_? and you can always wrap another `SELECT` around your statements (e.g. `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT … JOIN …) a`)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support the INTERSECT keyword. Full syntax of SELECT for 5.1 is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: @ david,can you please tell me how rewrite this query in course to attain the desired result